# Title: Issue with Cordova AdMob Pro Plugin after updating com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads to version 22.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, admob, ads

I am encountering issues with my Android project where I have integrated AdMob ads using the Cordova AdMob Pro plugin. The project was working fine with com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads version 19.0.0. However, after updating to version 22.0.0, I am facing errors in the Cordova AdMob Pro plugin files.
Cordova Plugin: I am using the Cordova AdMob Pro plugin, version .
Google Play services Ads Library: I updated from version 19.0.0 to version 22.0.0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.